# How to take values from command line into a pojo list

Tags: java, pojo

I have a main method like so:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Implement null checks
        ProfileData profileData = new ProfileData();


        try {
                profileData.setaJIO(args[0]!=null?args[0]:"");
                profileData.setAutopayCreated(args[1]!=null?args[1]:"");

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I have a ProfileData object which is a PoJo and has around 100 entries, I expect to load this object from commandline, however it is becoming tedious to populate all these entries manually in the main method. Is there a way I can do this in a for loop?

However I am stuck at the point as in how to refer to the pojo and its elements based on index in the main method? Any help would be appreciated

Looking at something which allows me to introduce a loop in the below snippet:

```
 try {
                profileData.setaJIO(args[0]!=null?args[0]:"");
                profileData.setAutopayCreated(args[1]!=null?args[1]:"");

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: You should simplify the design, you can introduce a `ArgumentParser` class. then main method will just call a method of it passing the complete array.This will shift the parsing responsibility from main to separate class.

Comment: I still have to so it manually

Comment: There is a complex way to do it and will require much lesser lines of code. You can do it using spring, having service class for each variable and in a for loop load the bean and execute method. sounds funny but if you have a hectic parsing to be done, will ease for you.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin you may write something like this:

```
class Test(map: Map<String, Any?>) {
    val name: String by map
    val age: String     by map

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Test[$name, $age]"
    }
}

fun parseArgs(args: Array<String>): Test {
    val zipArgs: List<Pair<String, String>> = args.zip(args.drop(1))

    val paramMap = zipArgs.mapNotNull { (name, param) ->
        if (!name.contains("-"))
            return@mapNotNull null

        name.substringAfter("-") to param
    }.toMap()

    return Test(paramMap)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val testArgs = arrayOf("-name", "testName", "-age", "123")

    val test = parseArgs(testArgs)

    println(test)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am using Java